# Retrain last inception or mobilenet layer to work with INPUT_SIZE 64x64 or 32x32

Tags: tensorflow

I want to retrain last inception or mobilenet layer so it would classify my own objects (about 5-15) 
Also I want this to work with INPUT_SIZE == 64x64 or 32x32 (not 224 like for the default inception model)

I found some articles about retraining models:
https://hackernoon.com/creating-insanely-fast-image-classifiers-with-mobilenet-in-tensorflow-f030ce0a2991
https://medium.com/@daj/creating-an-image-classifier-on-android-using-tensorflow-part-3-215d61cb5fcd

For mobilenet they say

> the input image size, either '224', '192', '160', or '128'

so I can't train with 64 or 32 (it's bad) https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L80

What about inception models? Can I somehow train models to work with small image input sizes (to get results faster)?

Objects which I want to classify from such small images will be already cropped from its parent image (for example from camera frames), it could be traffic/road signs cropped by fastest cascade classifiers (LBP/Haar) which were trained to detect everything that looks like sign's shapes/figures (triangle/rhombus,circle shapes)
So 64x64 images which fully include/contain only interested object should be enough for classification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not possible for classificators

but it become possible for tensorflow object detection api (we can set any input size) https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

Answer (score 0):

No you still can, use the smallest option which would be 128. It will just scale your 32 or 64 image up, which is fine.